# Can somebody help me to fix this ScrollView?

Tags: python, kivy

When I run the code below, I can't scroll. I would like to scroll the whole screen.

How can I achieve this?

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
#kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollableLabel>:
    FloatLayout:
        AsyncImage:
            source:''  #html here               
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, 'right':1}
            size_hint: 1, 1 
        AsyncImage:
            source:'' #html here 
            allow_stretch: True               
            keep_ratio: True             
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, 'right':0.13}
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15    
        Label:
            color: [66/255,134/255,244/255,1]
            height: 40
            font_size: 25
            italic: 1 
            bold: 1
            text: 'testing'
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.96, 'right': 0.24}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        Label:
            color: [66/255,134/255,244/255,1]
            height: 40
            font_size: 50
            italic: 1 
            bold: 1
            text: 'Testing\\nTesting1\\nTesting2\\nTesting3\\nTesting4'
            pos: root.x, root.y+25
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.1

''')

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runTouchApp(ScrollableLabel())
```

All the things show but the scroll bar does not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no need to repeat your question. Once is really enough. What actually happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I removed the repetition in the question for you. Please make sure to respond to comments, as people will lose interest in your question if you don't respond to comments in a timely manner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

First, you have to set `size_hint: (1, None)` so that you can set `height: 40` that determines how long you can scroll.

if you don't how long you have to set, you may set like this: `height: sum([c.height for c in self.children])`

Answer (score 0):

The child of a `ScrollView` must have at least one part of `size_hint` set to `None`, otherwise the default `size_hint: 1,1` makes the child the same size as the `ScrollView`, so there is nothing to scroll. So just change the initial part of your `ScrollableLabel` rule as:

```
<ScrollableLabel>:
    bar_width: 20
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 3000, 3000
```

My choice of `3000` is arbitrary, and just to insure that the `FloatLayout` is bigger than the `ScrollView`. And the `bar_width` makes the scrollbar easier to see.

Comment: If your problem is that you cannot see the scroll bar, I have edited my answer to make that more obvious.